# How to unit test responses of FutureCallback with ApacheAsyncHttpClient

Tags: java, kotlin, apache-httpclient-4.x, mockk, apache-httpasyncclient

I am trying to figure out how to unit test the callback methods of a `FutureCallback<HttpClient>`, but can't quite figure it out.

I have the following code:

```
val latch = CountDownLatch(10)
httpClient.execute(httpPost, object: FutureCallback<HttpResponse> {
                override fun completed(response: HttpResponse) {
                            val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                            response.entity.writeTo(outputStream)
                            result = DataObj.parseFrom(outputStream.toByteArray())
                        } catch (e: IOException) {
                            failed(e)
                        } catch (e: InvalidProtocolBufferException) {
                            e.printStackTrace()
                        }
                    }
                    latch.countDown()
                }

                override fun failed(e: Exception) {
                    logger.error(e.localizedMessage, e)
                    latch.countDown()
                }

                override fun cancelled() {
                    logger.error("Request cancelled.")
                    latch.countDown()
                }
            })
```

I'm unsure on how I can force the FutureCallback to excecute either completed, failed, or cancelled. Therefore the `latch.countDown()` is never called, meaning the test never ends.

What is the correct method to test this kind of asynchronous function?